# How to play AVI and MKV files in Windows Vista Media Center?

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, windows-media-center, avi, matroska

I've installed the DivX codec on my computer. I can play those files just fine in Windows Media Player. But when I tried it on Windows Media Center it crashes out. How can this problem be fixed?

NOTE: My OS is Vista Home Premium 64 bit (x64).

Comment: x86 or     x64?

Comment: Its vista home premium 64 bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the **Vista Codec Package** 5.4.2.

**[64-bit](http://www.start64.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=573&Itemid=72)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that mate, it works. and also if anybody wants to install just the 64 bit codec. http://shark007.net/x64components.html

Comment: you're quite welcome. the reason the divx codec was working for you with WMP is because in Windows Vista 64-bit, the integrated Windows Media Player 11 comes in both versions of 32-bit and 64-bit. However, the default Windows Media Player 11 has been set to the 32-bit edition. Due to compatibility issues, the 64-bit Windows Media Player 11 is left in the background, but it is being used with Media Center.  that's why i was assuming a 64bit Vista, but i preferred to wait if John's recommendation would 'fix it' for you, as it should.

Comment: -1 These so-called codec packs are evil and should be avoided at all costs - you have no idea what is in them and most if not all contain badly out of date or incompatible codecs @Davy_Landman's answer is the way to go.

Comment: "you have no idea what is in them" have i not? well, i beg to differ as i am well able to read descriptions and change logs. "most if not all contain badly out of date or incompatible codecs" can't be that incompatible if it works ... i will however upvote your comment because you took time to explain why you chose to downvote this answer. although i think comments like 'don't use codec packs or you're doomed long before the Mayan Doomsday' are neither helpful nor related in any way to this particular issue with Windows Media Center. this sort of comments is usually known as FUD.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't install the divx stuff or those K-Lite codec packs.

Just install the [ffdshow-tryouts](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/), this will decode all the video and audio you'll find.. For the support of MKV you'll have to install a directshow source splitter such as the [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.cs.msu.ru/mkv/). These two will fix 95% of your problems.

The only codec pack which would do more good than bad is the [CCCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Community_Codec_Pack), this one is recommended by the Matroska team (MKV/MKA designers) and I've used it once, and doesn't contain the usual codec pack junk.

Comment: Hey mate. Is this supposed to work right out of the box? Or Do I have to set it up to work with Windows Media Center?

Comment: The easiest would probably be CCCP, go to http://www.cccp-project.net/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page#Latest_CCCP_.28aka._Download_Here.21.29 and check the installation instructions. (Do remove the old stuff as they indicate)

Comment: and what good will CCCP do you, regarding a 64bit media player? it will sort out your 32bit WMP (which was playing the movies anyway thanks to the installed DivX codec), but not the 64bit variant used with Windows Media Center ... doh.

Comment: @Molly, regarding CCCP and 64bit, yes CCCP does not have 64bit filters. And while for this user it might not be the best answer, in general. Have problems: remove all the codec packs.. and install just the bare minimum.

Comment: i don't agree with general codec mayhem either. stick to one bundle only (to avoid conflicts) and keep it up to date on regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

[Media Control Plugin](http://damienbt.free.fr/index.php) will fix that.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Thanks anyway John.

Comment: Surprising, Its reported to be working at ghacks; http://www.ghacks.net/2007/02/08/add-codecs-to-windows-vista-media-center/

Answer (score 0):

If adding codecs like John has suggested does not work, you could try applications that work with their own codecs like [SMPlayer](http://www.ghacks.net/2007/09/08/smplayer-0551/) and VLC.

---

Update (after `Molly`'s comment and my reply).
You could also check the codecs installed on your system that match with the DivX file you intend to play.

This can be done with [Gspot v2.70a](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/). It will check integrity of the Divx file you want to play and
also check if you have necessary codecs installed in your system to be able to play it properly.

If this suggests your file is fine and codec's are installed for it,
the problem should be your Media Center installation
(which is my guess since WMP is playing the file;
But, its good to verify).

Comment: c'mon, the OP said he can play the videos in WMP alright, the issue is with Media Center. if the answer wasn't so far off, i'd upvote for SMPlayer :)

Comment: @Molly, You are right. Problem seems to be with the Media Center. I missed the earlier part of that question about WMP. If WMP is not good enough, the OP can tinker with a reinstall or codec checks OR as an alternative use on SMPlayer or VLC that do carry all necessary codes with them.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try installing [ffdshow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ffdshow). It could solve the issue of [.mkv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) file errors.